# Retrieving images from a remote mysql database to an android app

Tags: android

I would like to know how to retrieve an image from mysql database into an android application.
I am saving the folder name of the images in the database. The images are actually on my local machine. hence am not using Blob data type..
the php which I have written is as follows: these codes are working

```
 <html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <?php
     mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     mysql_select_db("vehicles");
     $res=mysql_query("select * from login");
    echo "<table>";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";?> <img src= "<?php echo $row["picture"];?>" height="200" width="200">
  <?php
   echo "</td>";
   echo "<td>"; echo $row["username"];echo "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
 }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

I would like to convert this data into json and retrieve the data on the android app..
I would be grateful if anybody could help me out..
Thanks in advance